# React can't make if statement with state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have 2 inputs one of them is username, another is password.

I want to make client side basic login pass control but it's not working.

Here is the problem, when i write correct username and password if statement going to else so it's not working but in login() function i can get with console log input value with `console.log(this.state.password`) eg.

in my component:

```
class Login extends Component {

    constructor() {
      super();
      this.state = {email : '', password: ''}
    }
    handleChange = (e) =>{ 
      this.setState({email: e.target.value});
    }
    password = (e) => {
      this.setState({password: e.target.value})
    }

    login() {
      if (this.state.email === 'admin@site.com' && this.state.password === 'asd123') {
        this.props.userLogin()
      } else {
        alert('username or password incorrect')
      }
    }


    render() {

    return (
      <Row className='justify-content-md-center login-panel'>
        <Col lg={12}>
        <Row className="justify-content-md-center">
          <Col lg={3}>
          <Form>
              <Form.Group>
                <Form.Control type="email" placeholder="Enter email" value={this.state.email} onChange={this.handleChange} />
              </Form.Group>
              <Form.Group controlId="formBasicPassword">
                <Form.Control type="password" placeholder="Password" value={this.state.password} onChange={this.password} />
              </Form.Group>
              <Button onClick={this.login}>
                Submit
              </Button>
          </Form>
          </Col>
        </Row>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: `<Button onClick={this.login.bind(this)} />`

Comment: not worked :( ..

Comment: Not recommended to bind function directly in render

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `this` keyword must point to the correct object, so you have the following options:

1. Use class field syntax (do not use constructor inside class). Some disadvantages are that every time you create a new object from the class, it will create a copy of all the methods, and you can't override class field functions in subclasses. Also, we can't use them to override superclass methods.

   ```
   class MyComponent extends React.Component{
   state={email : '', password: ''}; //no constructor used

   handleChange = (e) =>{            //arrow function
         this.setState({email: e.target.value});
       }

   render(){
   }
   }
   ```
2. If using a constructor, always bind the functions with `this`:

   ```
    class MyComponent extends React.Component{
    constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {email : '', password: ''}
    this.login= this.login.bind(this); //binding the login function
   }

   handleChange = (e) =>{    //no need to bind as it is an arrow function
         this.setState({email: e.target.value});
       }

   login() {
     if (this.state.email === 'admin@site.com' && this.state.password === 
   'asd123') {
       this.props.userLogin()
     } else {
       alert('username or password incorrect')
     }
   }

   render(){
   }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Your `login()` method is unbounded, so it doesn't know what `this` refers to. If you `console.log(this)` from `login()` you will see that it outputs some other object instead (usually a global one, like `window`).

This can be fixed in various ways, but the simplest one will be to change `login() {` to `login = () => {`. Similar to how you have `handleChange` defined.

Comment: Then there's another issue as well. But the above mentioned one has to be fixed anyway.

Comment: Try to dump the state from login() and see what it contains.

Comment: in login i tried to make console.log to state I’m getting the state value